# Showing empty PieChart according to interactivity in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I am implementing the `delete` method, and when I delete data in my list, it pop that data and send it to my `Piechart` component. What I want is, when I have a 0 value in my chartData object, just show the empty piechart.

Here is my delete button

```html
<v-btn class="btn" dark md color="error" @click="deleteHandle">
```

DeleteHandle method

```js
deleteHandle() {
  this.chartData.labels.pop();
  this.chartData.datasets[0].data.pop();
  this.chartData.datasets[0].backgroundColor.pop();
},
```

And my `PieChart.vue` component

```html
<template>
  <Pie
    v-if="loaded"
    id="my-chart-id"
    :options="chartOptions"
    :data="chartData"
  />
</template>

<script>
import {Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend} from 'chart.js';
import {Pie} from 'vue-chartjs';

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

export default {
  name: 'PieChart',
  components: {Pie},
  props: ['data', 'bgColor', 'labels'],
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [...this.labels],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [...this.data],
            backgroundColor: [...this.bgColor],
          },
        ],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        elements: {
          arc: {
            borderWidth: 0,
          },
        },
      },
      loaded: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You don't select which one to delete, just the last one (with `.pop`)? Also, what is not working exactly?

Comment: I would like to show empty piechart when my array have no element.

Comment: Replace the whole array with an empty one.